# Automatic sequence in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to cretae a automatic sequence number genaration using trigger but it is giving me following wrror while inserting the values.

```
ALTER TABLE sppinv_tblinventory_ex ADD (
  CONSTRAINT sppinv_tblinventory_PK PRIMARY KEY (uniqueid));

create  sequence row_seq ;

create or replace trigger row_count before insert on sppinv_tblinventory_ex
for each row

begin
 select row_seq.nextval into : new.uniqueid from dual;
end;
```

if I am excuting below then I am able to insert values

```
insert into sppinv_tblinventory_ex
select  row_seq.nextval,
  b.member_id,b.src_claim_nbr,b.client_nbr,b.src_platform_cd,
  b.suspense_date,b.batch_gen_key,b.bucket_name,b.grouper_rule,
  b.event_number,b.case_stat,b.case_stat_dt,b.assigned_to,
  b.assigned_on,b.followup_dt,b.release_ind,b.release_dt,
  b.viewtype
from sppinv_tblinventory b
```

When I am inserting the values with out uniqueID I am getting error like below

```
insert into sppinv_tblinventory_ex
select  b.member_id,b.src_claim_nbr,b.client_nbr,b.src_platform_cd,
  b.suspense_date,b.batch_gen_key,b.bucket_name,b.grouper_rule,
  b.event_number,b.case_stat,b.case_stat_dt,b.assigned_to,
  b.assigned_on,b.followup_dt,b.release_ind,b.release_dt,
  b.viewtype
from sppinv_tblinventory b

ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Note : I dont want to disable the trigger

Comment: It's good practice to supply the column list even when you're supplying every value, since columns might not be in the order you expect and it makes it easier to spot mistakes; it's required when you aren't supplying every value, as in this case.

Comment: You can also use keyword `DEFAULT` when you list all the columns, and want to "exclude" some values.

Answer (score 4):

ORA-00947: not enough values - means you have n number of columns in the table but you are only supplying values for (n-m) number of fields.

In your case, if you dont want to insert unique id, then you may have to do

```
Insert into sppinv_tblinventory_ex (col1, col2, col3.. coln) select (val1, val2, val3 .. valn)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are so many answers for this on internet...
Try removing the space before `new.uniqueid` ; and add a IF test like this :

```
create or replace trigger row_count
before insert on sppinv_tblinventory_ex
for each row
begin
    IF :new.uniqueid IS NULL THEN
        select row_seq.nextval into :new.uniqueid from dual;
    END IF;
end;
```

Now if you put `null` in the corresponding value field in your insert, it should work

Comment: That isn't the problem... the OP is getting not-enough-values on insert, not a trigger compilation error.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a IF test in the trigger code, if OP uses `null` in his first field it should work.

Comment: I agree there should not be a space between the colon and the `new`, but that isn't the issue being asked about. This doesn't solve the ORA-00947. If null was supplied as the first value in the select list it would work, but that's true without the `if` you added.